# jquery event is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a Invoice form and a jquery function.
In Invoice if i enter the quantity greater then the available quantity then i have to alert the user.

My problem is: Let the max quantity is 5, if i input data as 7 (single digit>max avail quantity) then my code is working fine. But if i enter two digigist number eg. 17(two digists>max avail quantity) then my alert box is not coming.
            I mean onkeyup my function is working  only with single digit.

How can i make it happening? Please help.

```
      $('input[name="quantity"]').keyup(function() 
       {  
    //problem is here
        var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var unitprice = $tr.find('input[name^="unitprice"]').val();

        var q = $tr.find('input[name^="quantity"]').val();
        var cq = $tr.find('input[name^="checkquantity"]').val();

        if(q>cq)
      {
      alert("Error: Quantity value exceeds then available quantity..Max Quantity is "+cq);
          //this works fine only if single digit is entered in textbox quantity
       }

         //----below are some other stuffs -these are working fine
        $tr.find('input[name^="sprice"]').val($(this).val() * unitprice); 
        var totalPrice = 0;
        $('input[name="sprice"]').each(function()
        {
            totalPrice += parseFloat(this.value);
            $('[name=subtotal]').val(totalPrice);
        });  
    });  
    --------------
    ------------
   // Form containing the above textboxes
        <input type="submit" id="submitbtnId" value="Save"/>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`q > cq` is comparing 2 strings, which is not what you want. You're trying to compare the numerical value of those strings.

Use this instead:

```
if ( +q > +cq)
{
    // alert your error
}
```

Note that by prefixing the variables with the `+` sign, you're converting them to a number.

---

Better yet, convert them to a number as soon as you get the values:

```
var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
var unitprice = +$tr.find('input[name^="unitprice"]').val();

var q = +$tr.find('input[name^="quantity"]').val();
var cq = +$tr.find('input[name^="checkquantity"]').val();

if ( q > cq )
{
    alert("Error: Quantity value exceeds then available quantity..Max Quantity is " + cq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parseInt()` to ensure you are comparing integers, not strings:

```
if (parseInt(q, 10) > parseInt(cq, 10)) {
    /* Rest of your code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your values are compared as *string*. If you want to compare Numbers, either use:

`parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`

or

`[..].val() * 1`, but this will return 'NaN' if its no digit, while parseInt() and parseFloat() will return 0